# Is there a better way to organize control/data control panels?

Tags: design-patterns

A client I am working with has about 15 screens of control panels, with varying lengths of data columns/rows (some with scrolling columns). All must provide some sort of editing feature pertaining to the data.

Although it's functional, I am wondering if this is the only way to design data/system/platform control features. I looked up other designs out there from data management systems like Splunk to User Management controls for regular websites - and they are all using tables with in-line editing and checkboxes.

Is there another way?

[image]

Comment: I realize OP is unlikely to ever read this, but this sounds a bit like the intention to reinvent the wheel. Of course there are other ways to do this e.g. in the example image, each row could have its own 'card' displaying info and editing options, perhaps displayed in a grid, but that's less space efficient than using a table. Tables lend themselves well to UIs like this. The question is: why exactly is OP investigating alternatives when a conventional and functional pattern is avaible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice custom approach from the past.

http://archive.group94.com/g94_2008/#/flash94/work

They distribute functioning to 2 levels. The result is nice looking and easier to use, less complicated.

Comment: Can you post the image inline? This leads to a 404 page.